# Fetch Image from Amazon using ASIN

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have ASIN id's for amazon with that I can go on the product page of Amazon now I want to fetch first Image from that page to power bi. I have this kind of urls "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000052YEN?th=1"

I already tried to give this links as ImageURL category but it isn't working. Please give me some solution if you have.

Thanks

Comment: if you know the image URLs then https://debajmecrm.com/how-to-display-a-url-as-image-in-power-bi-report-table/

Comment: No I don't know. I only have asin.